# Etymological dictionary with kanji type and compounds/radicals

Tags: discussion, kanji

I'm looking for an etymological dictionary preferably in online form to look up the [六書](https://www.tanoshiijapanese.com/dictionary/entry_details.cfm?entry_id=54223) (the six classes of kanji characters) and the compounds/radicals of a kanji. I know I can use [広辞苑](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C5%8Djien) (Kōjien). But the Mac version is not available in my region of the App Store (and the version you can download from the [website](https://www.logovista.co.jp/lverp/information/support/download/jiten_updata/KOJIEN6.html#02) fails to install).

Comment: I would check out https://www.outlier-linguistics.com/products/outlier-kanji-dictionary-essentials-edition - I can’t directly vouch for the Japanese edition, but the Chinese edition is very good. Note that 六書 is a *traditional* classification scheme - many characters don’t fit cleanly into the categories, and some of the categories (like *derivative cognates*) don’t really even mean anything concrete.

Comment: I bought the dictionary and it is super helpful with dissecting kanji. Thanks a lot!